# Linear regression - results depending on the scale of the inputs

Tags: regression, scale-invariance

Why is there a difference in p-values for the following model
$$
y = a + b_1x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_{12}x_1x_2 + \epsilon
$$
depending on the scale of the x's?

```
> # response variable
> y <- rnorm(8, mean=17, sd=1.2)
> 
> # model 1
> x1 <- c(1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1)
> x2 <- c(-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1)
> fit1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1*x2)
> 
> # model 2 (factors transformation)
> z1 <- x1 * 7.5 + 47.5
> z2 <- x2 * 11.5 + 67.5 
> fit2 <- lm(y ~ z1 + z2 + z1*z2)
> 
> # comparison
> summary(fit1)$coef
              Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 17.6901204  0.3394185 52.1189021 8.111573e-07
x1           0.3434611  0.3394185  1.0119103 3.688180e-01
x2           0.0928959  0.3394185  0.2736913 7.978731e-01
x1:x2       -0.1541870  0.3394185 -0.4542681 6.731943e-01

> summary(fit2)$coef
                    Estimate   Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
    (Intercept)  9.237873473 12.957889026  0.7129150 0.5152809
    z1           0.166462912  0.269459429  0.6177661 0.5701650
    z2           0.092992493  0.189241898  0.4913948 0.6488902
    z1:z2       -0.001787676  0.003935287 -0.4542681 0.6731943
```

Comment: This is because the least square estimates are NOT affine invariant.

Comment: Thank you Zhanxiong. I am not speaking about the parameter estimates but rather about the pvalues. I would expect a significant variable under a parametrisation to be significant under the other parametrisation as well...

Comment: The problem is, you transformed $x_1$ and $x_2$ by DIFFERENT scales, therefore, you essentially changed the relationship between response and explanatory variables, hence the p-values changed. If the change of slopes for $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the same, then it is reasonable (and can be proved) the p-values for these two explanatory variables would be unchanged (the p-value for intercept, however, will still change).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Let's compare the two models.**

The original one is clearly and well expressed in the question,

$$y = a + b_1x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_{12}x_1x_2 + \epsilon.$$

Let's write the second model as

$$y = a^\prime + b^\prime_1 z_1 + b^\prime_2 z_2 + b^\prime_{12}z_1z_2 + \delta.$$

Because the values of the numbers 7.5, 47.5, etc. are of little interest, let's just name them with Greek letters:

$$z_i = \alpha_i x_i + \gamma_i.$$

We know them; they are constant; they will not need to be estimated.

Plugging these equations into the second model shows how it attempts to relate $y$ to the $x_i$:

$$\eqalign{
y &= &a^\prime + b^\prime_1 (\alpha_1 x_1 + \gamma_1) + b^\prime_2 (\alpha_2 x_2 + \gamma_2) + b^\prime_{12}(\alpha_1 x_1 + \gamma_1)(\alpha_2 x_2 + \gamma_2) + \delta \\
&= &(a^\prime + b^\prime_1\gamma_1 + b^\prime_2\gamma_2 + b^\prime_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2) + (b^\prime_1\alpha_1 + b^\prime_{12} \gamma_2\alpha_1)x_1 + (b^\prime_2\alpha_2 + b^\prime_{12}\gamma_1\alpha_2)x_2 \\
&&+ (b^\prime_{12}\alpha_1\alpha_2)x_1x_2 + \delta.
}$$

Recalling that the default tests conducted by software compare coefficients to *zeros*, it's easy to compare the results, line by line, to the output for the first ($x$) model:

- The errors are modeled in the same way: $\epsilon = \delta$.  Therefore the fits (predictions) will be the same and so will the residuals.  **These are identical models,** merely reparameterized.
- The test of the intercept compares $a^\prime + b^\prime_1\gamma_1 + b^\prime_2\gamma_2 + b^\prime_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2$ to $0$.
- The tests of the coefficients compare $b^\prime_1\alpha_1 + b^\prime_{12} \gamma_2\alpha_1$ and $b^\prime_2\alpha_2 + b^\prime_{12}\gamma_1\alpha_2$ to $0$.
- The test of the interaction term compares $b^\prime_{12}\alpha_1\alpha_2$ to $0$.

**Only in the last case** is there a simple relationship to the tests in the second model (involving only the primed coefficients): because rescaling $b^\prime$ by $\alpha_1\alpha_2$ also scales its standard error by the same amount, the $t$ statistic (which is the ratio of the estimate to its SE) does not change.  Sure enough, the p-values for the interaction terms in both outputs agree because `6.731943e-01` is the same number as `0.67319431` (to within the displayed precision).

In the other cases (the intercept and coefficients of the $x_i$), the coefficients are *linear functions* of the coefficients for the second model.  Their estimates will therefore be the very same linear functions of the estimated coefficients.

We can use this to work out the exact relationships in the two outputs *provided we have information about the covariances of the estimates.*  This is because the standard errors of the linear combinations for the first three coefficients will depend on the variances of the estimates and their covariances.  For instance,

$$\text{var}(\hat{b}_1) = \text{var}(\hat b^\prime_1\alpha_1 + \hat b^\prime_{12} \gamma_2\alpha_1) = \alpha_1^2\text{var}(\hat b^\prime_1) + (\gamma_2\alpha_1)^2\text{var}(\hat b^\prime_{12}) + 2\alpha_1^2\gamma_2\text{cov}(\hat b^\prime_1, \hat b^\prime_{12}). $$

(The hats over the letters denote data-based estimates, as usual.)

---

In theory, **it matters not which model you choose.**  It is convenient, however, to use one where the automatic tests conducted by the software are relevant for your analytical purposes.  Let that guide how you re-express the independent variables in a regression.

Answer (score 2):

The $p$-values did not change because of the rescaling, but because you added constants to the variable. The intercept is the expected value of `y` when all explanatory variables are 0. The $p$-value is the test of the hypothesis that that conditional mean is equal to 0. So if you add a constant to one or more of the explanatory variables, then you are testing a different null-hypothesis and you get a different $p$-value. For example, say one of your explanatory variables is year of birth. Without centering your intercept refers to a person born in year 0, which is quite often a bit of an extrapolation. If You centered the year of birth by subtracting 1960, the intercept will refer to someone born in 1960.

The main effects (`x1`, `x2`, `z1`, and `z2`) are also influenced by the constant, because you added an interaction term. `x1` is the effect of `x1` when `x2` is 0. So say `x2` is year of birth, then `x1` is the effect of `x1` for someone quite old. Again you change this by centering your variable at say someone born in 1960 to get a more meaningful effect of `x1`. But you get a very null hypothesis, and the $p$-value should change.

Notice that the $p$-value of the interaction terms (`x1:x2` and `z1:z2`) remain unchanged ($6.731943 \times 10^{-1} = 0.6731943$). This is due to the fact that the interpretation of this interaction is not affected by any constants added to the model.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show @Zhanxiong last comment:

```
# response variable
y <- rnorm(8, mean=17, sd=1.2)

# model 1
x1 <- c(1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1)
x2 <- c(-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1)
fit1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1*x2)

# model 2 (factors transformation - no addtion)
z1 <- x1 * 7.5 
z2 <- x2 * 11.5  
fit2 <- lm(y ~ z1 + z2 + z1*z2)

summary(fit1)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  17.2558     0.2382  72.439 2.18e-07 ***
x1            0.1923     0.2382   0.807    0.465    
x2            0.1152     0.2382   0.484    0.654    
x1*x2         0.1691     0.2382   0.710    0.517 

summary(fit2)
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 17.255837   0.238213  72.439 2.18e-07 ***
z1           0.025641   0.031762   0.807    0.465    
z2           0.010018   0.020714   0.484    0.654    
z1*z2        0.001960   0.002762   0.710    0.517
```