When should I standardize, before or after a regression?
I have a panel dataset and my dependent variable is the logit-transformed share of farm workers on long-term contracts. I am particularly interested in the effects of two variables, pastoral focus in agriculture, represented by variable 'pastoral', and the presence of horses, represented by 'horse'. The impact of these variables changes over time, and I run a model with an interaction term:
model <- lm(logitshare ~ pastoral + pastoral:factor(year) + horse + horse:factor(year) +
            other variables, data = mydata)

I need to compare the relative importance of variables and use two approaches, standardizing either before or after running a regression. The results are visibly different.
.
Column 'model' shows the case when regression was run on non-standardized coefficients, and standardization was done post-factum using lm.beta. ModelST was run on coefficients transformed with the R's scale function. Which approach is more reliable?

Thry should give the same results.  What are you using to scale the data?   Looks like lm.beta just calls Rs scale() function

That was my expectation, but the results are different. I use zscore (from mosaic) or scale to standardize the variables, and take standardized coefficients from lm.beta: betas <- lm.beta(model);
estimates = betas$standardized.coefficients)

So the p-values changed too? Did you also standardize the year? Can you post the outputs?

Are categorical variables handled in the same way? While it's not completely meaningless to standardize those it's usually not the default.

I added a summary of my results. P-values change too; I tried standardizing the year but the coefficcients remain the same, the only change is that the names of interaction variables change from pastoral:factor(Year)1881 to pastS:factor(Year)-0.464984760664347  and the like which I believe represents the standardized value of Year.

What is R doing to scale factors?  (I am short on time right now, but that looks like one possible issue).  Also, why have year as a factor?

Your models lack a main effect for Year.

@Peter Flom: R subtracts the mean and divides by standard deviation, for variable x: mydata %>% mutate(x_scale = scale(x), x_man = (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)) %>% filter(!x_scale == x_man) the results are identical. I work with census data, and it is common to treat year as a categorical variable. I tried running the model with continuous year, but the same issue (different results, as in my question) persists.

@rolando2: could you be a bit more specific?

Year appears only as part of interactions.

I've just added factor(Year) as an additional explanatory variable. There are some marginal changes, but the big problem (difference in results) remains. It even got 'worse' in a sense that the coefficients for this variable are negative in one approach and positive in the other.

Please explain exactly how you standardized the variables.  The only correct way must be equivalent to standardizing columns of a design matrix: is that what you did or not?  And if you did, what variable codings did you use to construct that design matrix?

@whuber: I did this in a fairly simple way, applying R's scale function to all variables except the year. This means decentring and dividing by standard deviation, but this is done across all years and I have a feeling that something is not quite right.

Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162399 for one example of why the details matter so much.  I suspect your question might be the same as that one, but it's not clear that's the case.

lm.beta() standardizes based on the model matrix by multiplying the estimated coefficient by the standard deviation of the corresponding term. That means if you have interaction terms in the model, it will multiply the interaction coefficient by the standard deviation of the product of the variables. This makes little sense and does not ease interpretation. You should instead standardize your continuous predictors using scale() before including them in the model. See below:
library(lm.beta)
data("lalonde", package = "MatchIt")

#Fit original model
fit <- lm(re78 ~ age * educ, data = lalonde,
          x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
coef(fit)
#> (Intercept)         age        educ    age:educ 
#>  4356.72477   -68.18635   -49.80549    17.33115

cbind(
  coef(lm.beta(fit)), #lm.beta()
  coef(fit) * apply(model.matrix(fit), 2, sd) / sd(fit$y) #manual standardization
)
#>                    [,1]        [,2]
#> (Intercept)          NA  0.00000000
#> age         -0.09018690 -0.09018690
#> educ        -0.01752238 -0.01752238
#> age:educ     0.28200390  0.28200390

#Correctly scale variables before modeling
fit2 <- lm(scale(re78) ~ scale(age) * scale(educ), data = lalonde)
coef(fit2)
#>            (Intercept)             scale(age)            scale(educ) 
#>            0.007556313            0.145204211            0.149321385 
#> scale(age):scale(educ) 
#>            0.060249348

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0
The coefficient on the interaction term in the post-hoc standardized model (.28) has no interpretation. The coefficient on the interaction term in the pre-standardized model has the usual interpretation: for a 1-standard deviation increase in educ, the effect of a 1-standard deviation increase of age on the standardized outcome increases by .06.
You should not use lm.beta() if your model has any interactions in it. If you have no interactions (or squared terms, etc.), then you should get the same values if you standardized before or after fitting as indicated by Shawn.

Ah, your answer is a bit more complete than mine. The commentary on the lm.beta effects on the model matrix, which I hadn't considered when first running this, is probably key to answering OP's question (+1).

@Noah: Thank you very much, it's a great answer. I am sorry for the late response, I have flu and was not well. Your explanation is very clear, and yet there is one aspect which I cannot quite understand. Using the same dataset:    fit <- lm(re78 ~ age + age : factor(race), data = lalonde)
fit_scaled <- lm(scale(re78) ~ scale(age) + scale(age) : factor(race), data = lalonde)
cbind(coef(fit), coef(fit_scaled))

I am sorry it is difficult to insert a code here. The output is:
(Intercept)            4997.20446 -0.005548323
age                      27.37456  0.074391024
age:factor(race)hispan   47.70143 -0.061904176
age:factor(race)white    64.26585  0.062937769  so that the first model shows that for a Hispanic person, the effect of age is positive, whilst in the scaled model it is negative. How could this be?

It shouldn't be the case that the coefficients vary based on when the numeric variables are standardized (though note in Noah's answer that this can change based off the interactions / factor variables, which he nicely details in his own post). I show below in R with a basic example of how using standardize betas from lm.beta equal the same thing as a regression fit with pre-standardized variables. First I load the lm.beta package and fit a basic model with the iris data in fit1.
#### Load Library ####
library(lm.beta)

#### Standard Fit ####
fit1 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width, iris)

This first fit we will check the standardized betas with later. We can fit a separate regression where we scale/standardize before fitting like below into fit2:
#### Pre-Treatment ####
Scale.Length <- scale(iris$Petal.Length)
Scale.Petal <- scale(iris$Petal.Width)
Scale.Sepal <- scale(iris$Sepal.Width)

fit2 <- lm(Scale.Length ~ Scale.Petal + Scale.Sepal)

You should notice that running the standardized coefficients and the pre-scaled versions elicit the same answers.
#### Check Standardized Coefficients ####
lm.beta(fit1) # standardized betas for raw data
lm.beta(fit2) # since data is already standardized, this is the same
coef(fit2) # same thing since standardized data

I would show your exact code to determine what is exactly wrong with your standardization. All we have is your explanation and the original model fit. I assume your problem is related to what Noah indicates in his own answer given the nature of your model.
